# How to validate a multiple custom UItextfield value which is created by UITableViewCell in custom file using objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created an outlet for UItextfield in a custom.h file and created 3 UITextfields using tableviewcell and also assigned tag to each of the textfields. But I don't know how to get those textfield values and also validate them. When all the Textfield values are correct, it should show successful alert message when clicked on a button.
I don't want to use 3rd party libraries.

Comment: Can you be more specific on your requirement? Are you using a custom textfield within a table view cell?

Comment: yes, i m using custom textfield within a table view cell and more important i want to validate them. My textfield are name, phone and email.

Answer (score -1):

Add a listener to the textfield field change in the cell and create a delegate that is held by the controller. When creating a cell, you need to add a flag to the cell. When the proxy method is implemented, the correctness of the field of the textfiled is determined. The created flag is used to distinguish the cell from the textfield and recorded in the nsarray.

Comment: Can you rephrase your answer? I have a hard time understanding what you want to say

Comment: The language expression is not detailed enough, I will post the code